# Simplest possible gradle project to run groovy scripts

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a bunch of groovy scripts that work just fine. However, they always have the 'cold start' problem of loading the entire JVM. I would like to run them with gradle as tasks (without defining them as tasks so they can run without gradle) so I can keep gradle in daemon mode and thus 'hot'

My current project doesn't really work because one the groovy files I need is not on the classpath. I could manually load it but I suspect there is something simpler (convention?)

Here is a tree view of my repo

```
$ tree
.
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── BBScm.groovy
    ├── Scm.groovy
    ├── StashScm.groovy
    ├── mixins.groovy
    └── stash.groovy
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

group 'org.bongiorno'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    groovyScript
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.2'
}

task analyze {

    doLast{
        apply from: 'src/stash.groovy'
    }
}
```

The error I get is pretty clear:

```
  script '/Users/cbongiorno/dev/mystuff/stash/src/stash.groovy': 22: unable to resolve class StashScm 
   @ line 22, column 13.
     Scm stash = new StashScm(u: srcUser, p: srcPass, baseUrl: 'https://xxxxx')
             ^
```

To be clear: My ask is what is the dead simplest way to do this? 'Cause I can definitely hack my way past this issue

Comment: Have you looked at: https://kobo.github.io/groovyserv/

Comment: I just installed it and I am giving it a go... so far, so good. In a way, it's better than the idea I had because it's more intuitive. On the other hand, it's yet another tool to install. Will experiment. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I have used it now a bit and it has the exact same error - I think what I am seeing is the equivalent of a compile error and not a runtime error. I think the groovy compiler has no idea what I am even talking about even though this file is right next to the one running. I think the reason I haven't encountered this problem sooner is because the whole directory of code is added as src in intellij

Answer (score 0):

The `src` is where you put code to compile and in last term to build an artifact but if you want to add code (in source form) you must use the `buildSrc` directory

You can find more documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources

in the same way the `depedencies` section is where you locate dependencies for your project but if you have dependencies in your `build` logic you use the `build` section where you specify it ussing the `classpath` word instead of `compile`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21022189)

Comment: @Alex.K. you are right. Sorry, I'll try to explain my answer

Comment: Ok, using this approach I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport`

Comment: So I assume right now gradle is able to find your script. Are you using Grappe in it? Can you provide the code?